# SQL Query - How to not include some results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I apologize if this question was asked before I just couldn't correctly formalize it. I have a code column in a table and want to query it but remove some elements with some particular code. Say I want to take elements with code starting from 4 but not include the elements with code whose 6-th number is 9 (1121290).

The code column contains string of numbers with max-length of 8 char. and I want to take almost everything that starts with 4 except elements that start with 411, 427 and 428

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I am a newbie for the moment I am using PostgreSQL and my query is : SELECT * FROM econom_classifier WHERE code LIKE '4%' and LENGTH(code) = 8;

Comment: Show us some sample data, show us your code that you have right now, explain in more detail what you'd want to select and what you'd like to omit. Also - please tell us what **database** you're using - SQL is just the structured query language, and stuff like this (string handling) can be very vendor-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can give query like this:--

I have column element with 6 digit codes.

I am fetching element whose 1st digit is 4 or 6th is 9.

we have to use `%` and `_` for fetching..

```
SELECT element  FROM "table" WHERE element LIKE '%4____9%';
```

try this it will work.

Everything that starts with 4 except elements that start with 411, 427 and 428 :-

```
 SELECT element  FROM "table" WHERE element LIKE '%4__';
```

1st digit is 4 and 6th is not 9: I tested this one it is working fine try this :-

```
SELECT element  
FROM "table" 
WHERE element NOT LIKE '%_____9' and element LIKE '%4_____'
```

Comment: but I don't want to include elements whose 6-th digit is 9

Comment: SELECT 'element'  FROM `table` WHERE `element` LIKE '%4'; will include  411, 427 and 428

Comment: yes.. boss but i write query for only that who start from 4.. this SELECT 'element' FROM table WHERE element LIKE '%4'; will give u all result which has 4 in starting or middle or in last.. that's y i specify that one..

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to simply spell out each condition in the where clause:

```
WHERE code like '4____9%' AND code NOT LIKE '411%' AND code NOT LIKE '427%' AND code NOT LIKE '428%'
```

The extra conditions won't hurt the query's efficiency much; it's going to have to scan every single row starting with *4* anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "CODE" field is varchar and you are using SQL Server,
you can use the below Query

```
select * from yourTable
where code like '4%'
AND CHARINDEX('9',code)<>6
```

Comment: @vikii when "like '4%'" means starts with 4, Please run the query once before downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more compact version.

```
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE code IN ('4%') and code NOT IN ('411%','427%', '428%','_____9%');`
```