# SQL Query Where Field DOES NOT Contain a Digit

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with an address street, I want to make sure the address contains the street as well as house/building number (saxon 17)
I want to write an SQL query to find rows where field address does not contain a numeric value. How can I do this?

Comment: see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612356/sql-query-how-to-not-include-some-results

Comment: @Aardappelkroket thanks but the suggested answer is treating an explicit example rule, going over the answers there are even suggestions to be as specific as possible in my case it can be an combination of numbers and number length that is why i want to find all rows with no number at the address field

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done using a regular expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where address_column !~ '[0-9]'
```

More details about regular expressions and pattern matching can be found in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Also mind that this is a solution for values that don't contain any digits. Therefore "B-1" will also be filtered out. For a "not a digit" condition - use regex '^[0-9]*$'.